# how to differentiate request empty string and null on laravel

Tags: laravel-5

in php we can do

```
isset($_POST['name'])
```

so that user submit empty text can be detected.

but in laravel

```
$request->has('name')
```

return null on empty string too.

I need to find a way to tell if it is an empty string or the field not posted at all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use exists() method in request instance. If you want to check if there is value in request check:

```
$request->has('key');
```

if you want to check if the key is exists use:

```
$request->exists('key');
```

Comment: Correct me if I were wrong. In Laravel 5.4 and above, all empty strings are converted to null. And using $request->has('key') will return a value of null. So I think you cannot use $request->has('key') to check if there is a value for a key.

Comment: `$request->has('key')` returns true so long as that param has been submitted regardless of the value
`$request->filled('key')` returns false if null or an empty string `""` is submitted
`$request->input('key', '')` returns null if the user submits `""` but will apply the default (second param) if the key is absent from the request

Answer (score 62):

If you're using laravel 5.4 or above, by default it uses a middleware to convert all empty strings to null.

In App\Http\Kernel.php:
          `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class`

Comment out this middleware to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Man, you just saved my day.

Comment: Thanks, that was hard to find out