# Why can't I save an empty string from an input request directly into a corresponding session variable?

Tags: laravel, session, request

I am receiving some data in my controller which I want to be able to store in session variables. Some fields might contain empty strings, which is fine: I want to save those too, exactly as they are.

Here's the issue, though:

```
if($request->has('foobar')){
    // yup, confirmed it's there
}

if($request->foobar == ''){
    // yup, confirmed it's an empty string
}

session()->put('foobar', $request->foobar); // Nope! session()->put() method apparently refuses to add a request variable like this if it's an empty string?
session()->save();

if(session()->has('foobar')){
    // nope, it ain't there.
}

// I have to use this dumb workaround instead:

$my_foobar = $request->foobar;

if($request->foobar == ''){
    $my_foobar = '';
}

session()->put('foobar', $my_foobar); // this actually works: it sets the session variable to an empty string as I want
session()->save();

if(session()->has('foobar')){
    // yes, now it's there. hooray. but why? 
}
```

If I can add an empty string to a session, and if the request variable equates to an empty string, then why can't I add it directly? Can anyone advise on what is going on here? Thanks. This is using Laravel 8.

Comment: `session()->put('foorbar', $request->foorbar);` be careful with the differences between "foobar" and "foo**r**bar"

Comment: @JuanMartínPagella oops- well spotted, edited now, thanks. Just a typo in my example though, not the cause of the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so as it turns out--

```
if($request->foobar == ''){
    // this passes
}

if($request->foobar === ''){
    // but this doesn't (note the strict '===' operator)
}
```

That's because the request value is actually `null`:

```
if(is_null($request->foobar)){
    // yes, passes
}
```

And here's why: Laravel 5.4+ uses a `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` Middleware by default. See Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class, // this one
];
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028446/521392) for pointing me in the right direction.